# How to determine what is causing Garbage Collection (GC) Events in ng-Repeat Angular.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs, garbage-collection

I have a ajax call to the server to retrieve some JSON data, and then set a scoped variable "array" to a JSON array.

The 2D array contains arrays, which can be undefined, or containing objects

After the array variable is set, the ng-repeat in the HTML updates to reflect the new array.

During this process until the end of the HTML reflecting the new update, there are numerous GC events and animation events that get fired, holding up any processing on the page.

[image: timeline profile]

If anyone has seen this kind of behaviour in ng-repeat, or suspects anything that might cause this, please let me know.

Cheers!

Comment: getting rid of the animation would eliminate most of the work shown. Garbage Collection runs when it needs to, and does not indicate undesired operation, especially when it only pauses a few millis.

Comment: I've gotten rid of the animation. It gives marginal performance increase, GC events are still a massive problem. http://i.imgur.com/hvCkoDr.png

Comment: i'm not sure i understand what you mean by "massive problem". cars burns gas, some more than others, but it's how they get work done, not a problem per se. using a high-level abstraction like angular implies you're not concerned about bare-metal machine interactions, which angular manages for you, and along with the other stuff it manages for you, does take some pTime. i don't see soo many GCs that it looks like a problem, but maybe you can describe the undesired side-effects better than a static image conveys it.